# Add variable JSON with apache velocity

Tags: vtl

I need to able to dynamically add a variable to a JSON string, then escape it. Is it possible to do this with VTL?

Here is my case

```
#set( $foo = "bar" )
#set( $input = $util.escapeJavaScript( '{"foo": $foo }' ))
```

Where $foo would be the dynamically added variable to the JSON string i want to escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't explicitly add variables to the JSON but a work around was to create an array of objects, where I would manually escape dynamically added object, as well as adding the incoming body JSON.

In my case it was

```
#set( $body = $util.escapeJavaScript( $input.json('$') )) 
{
    "input": "[$body, {\"id\":\"$context.requestId\" }]"
}
```